# Responsive row of same-height elements breaks to two rows in small breakpoint

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have 6 cells of data, in medium+ breakpoints, they are all in the same row and the same height; in the small breakpoint, there are 3 per row, and everything within the row is the same height.

I had initially tried to use `display: table-cell;`, and was able to achieve both scenarios separately, but the markup needed to change.  Is there a way to make this approach work?

I know flexbox could be an option, but I cannot use it, as I need to support IE9.

Would like to solve this without the use of any JS.

**tl;dr**

- 3 cells in a row for small viewports
- 6 cells in a row for medium viewports
- All cells in a row should be the same height
- Dynamic height, based on content length
- No JS - CSS/Markup only.
- Support for IE9+.

---

**Works in small breakpoint (3 per row):**

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16.66667%; /* 1/6 */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .cell {
    width: 33.33333%; /* 1/3 */
    background: #eee; /* Just to see when the breakpoint is applied */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell 1 Pellentesque pretium neque at lacinia faucibus.</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell 4</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 5</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu ornare mi. Ut convallis suscipit sapien, at feugiat tellus commodo nec.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Works in medium+ breakpoints (6 per row):**

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16.66667%; /* 1/6 */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .cell {
    width: 33.33333%; /* 1/3 */
    background: #eee; /* Just to see when the breakpoint is applied */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell 1 Pellentesque pretium neque at lacinia faucibus.</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 3</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 4</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 5</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu ornare mi. Ut convallis suscipit sapien, at feugiat tellus commodo nec.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Since its a tabular data I would suggest to go with Table...

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.cell {
  width: 16.66667%;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .cell {
    width: 33.33333%; /* 1/3 */
    background: yellow; /* Just to see when the breakpoint is applied */
  }
}



<table class="table" >
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell">Cell 1 Pellentesque pretium neque</td>
    <td class="cell">Cell 2</td>
    <td class="cell">Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell">Cell 4</td>
    <td class="cell">Cell 5</td>
    <td class="cell">Cell 6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu ornare mi. Ut convallis suscipit sapien, at feugiat tellus commodo nec.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dinker/k9pun3mn/)

Comment: I want it to be 1 row, 6 across in 500px+ viewports.  Additionally, this is just sample data, the actual data is not tabular.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly this is what you want to achieve... here I am using bootstrap listGrid concept to achieve this.

```css
 .cell {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   text-align: center;
   height: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="table">
  <div class="cell col-xs-4 col-sm-2">Cell 1 Pellentesque pretium neque at lacinia faucibus.</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-4 col-sm-2">Cell 2</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-4 col-sm-2">Cell 3</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-4 col-sm-2">Cell 4</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-4 col-sm-2">Cell 5</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-4 col-sm-2">Cell 6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu ornare mi. Ut convallis suscipit sapien, at feugiat tellus commodo nec.</div>
</div>
```

Note1: If in case you do not want to use bootstrap let me know, I can find some other solution.

Note2: Bootstrap has pre-define values in pexels for devices, and if you want to change as per your need you can  at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: I cannot hardcode the height in my situation (that's why I had tried using table/cell); this is basically how I worked around it, having JS do the calculation based on the content height, but I was hoping for a CSS-only version.

Comment: ohk so according to me you must provide some height or use table/cell or use table structure format. but since you do not want to hardcode the height, the last option I think if you can use min-height ?? just think of it. if that can fix the issue.

Comment: ya, that is where I landed too, hence the question.  `min-height` won't work for me, since it needs to be the same height, regardless of the amount of content (tons or only a little).